# remove leading 0 from a string, objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing leading zeroes from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657833/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-string)

I need to remove 0 from the beginning of a string and prevent leading 0s when user input the number, how can I do it?

For example: 
user input: 000090
display: 90

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use an `NSScanner`:

```
NSString *string = @"000090";
NSCharacterSet *nonzeroNumberCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:nonzeroNumberCharacterSet intoString:nil];
NSString *remainder = nil;
NSCharacterSet *emptyCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:emptyCharacterSet intoString:&remainder];
```

At this point `remainder` is equal to `@"90"`.

Equivalently, one could replace the lines

```
NSCharacterSet *nonzeroNumberCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
```

with

```
NSCharacterSet *zeroNumberCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:zeroNumberCharacterSet intoString:nil];
```

to scan past all the zeros rather than to scan until the first non-zero number.

One drawback of this approach is that if the original string is `@"000000000"`, the resulting string will be empty.